# SQL INNER JOIN Multiple Tables and columns

Tags: mysql, sql

The Problem:

```
Construct the SQL statement to find all of the people that have meetings only before Dec. 25, 2016 at noon using INNER JOINs. Display the following columns:
 Person’s first name
 Person’s last name
 Meeting ID
 Meeting start date and time
 Meeting end date and time
```

The Tables:
There are 5 tables in this database(person, building, room, meeting, person_meeting

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| person_id | first_name | last_name  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|         1 | Tom        | Hanks      |
|         2 | Anne       | Hathaway   |
|         3 | Tom        | Cruise     |
|         4 | Meryl      | Streep     |
|         5 | Chris      | Pratt      |
|         6 | Halle      | Berry      |
|         7 | Robert     | De Niro    |
|         8 | Julia      | Roberts    |
|         9 | Denzel     | Washington |
|        10 | Melissa    | McCarthy   |
+-----------+------------+------------+

+-------------+----------------------+
| building_id | building_name        |
+-------------+----------------------+
|           1 | Headquarters         |
|           2 | Main Street Buidling |
+-------------+----------------------+

+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| room_id | room_number | building_id | capacity |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|       1 | 100         |           1 |        5 |
|       2 | 200         |           1 |        4 |
|       3 | 300         |           1 |       10 |
|       4 | 10          |           2 |        4 |
|       5 | 20          |           2 |        4 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------+

+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| meeting_id | room_id | meeting_start       | meeting_end         |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |       1 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          2 |       1 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          3 |       1 | 2016-12-25 11:00:00 | 2016-12-25 12:00:00 |
|          4 |       2 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          5 |       4 | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | 2016-12-25 10:00:00 |
|          6 |       5 | 2016-12-25 14:00:00 | 2016-12-25 16:00:00 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+

+-----------+------------+
| person_id | meeting_id |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |
|        10 |          1 |
|         1 |          2 |
|         2 |          2 |
|         3 |          2 |
|         4 |          2 |
|         5 |          2 |
|         6 |          2 |
|         7 |          2 |
|         8 |          2 |
|         9 |          3 |
|        10 |          3 |
|         1 |          4 |
|         2 |          4 |
|         8 |          5 |
|         9 |          5 |
|         1 |          6 |
|         2 |          6 |
|         3 |          6 |
+-----------+------------+
```

My Solution so Far:

SELECT first_name,last_name ,building_name,meeting_start,meeting_end
FROM person P
INNER JOIN building B
ON P.person_id=PM.person_id
INNER JOIN person_meeting PM
    ON M.room_id

I'm having trouble completing the SQL statement, please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

this might do the trick for you. I used aliases for each of the tables in the join and used them in the select statements for the columns you needed. Then I joined the needed tables and in the `where` it determines the ones with a `meeting_end` before dec 12 at noon. (i assume, if you wanted it start just switch it to `meeting_start`)

```
select p.first_name,p.last_name,pm.meeting_id,m.meeting_start,m.meeting_end from person p
inner join person_meeting pm on pm.person_id = p.person_id
inner join meeting m on m.meeting_id = pm.meeting_id
where m.meeting_end > '2016-12-25 12:00:00'
```

Comment: this help at all?